# How to move files from my web server to my (local) dev machine?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, ubuntu-10.04, website, scp

I am running a headless Linux Ubuntu 10.0.4 on my server. I only allow access to the server using ssh (and scp).

I have a dev machine situated at home (behind a firewall) and I am able to copy files from my local (dev) machine to the server using scp. However, I now want to transfer files the other way, i.e. from the server to my dev machine.

Anyone knows the best way to do this?. BTW, I am running same OS on my dev machine (Ubuntu 10.0.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just scp it back to your home machine

`scp username@tohostname:/remotefile /newlocalfile`

you can use the '-r' switch for recursive copying

Comment: Doh!, I'm embarrased I had to ask such a stupid question. (Hangs head in shame)

Comment: Sometimes we just worked way too hard on a day, and forgot to consult captain obvious =)

Answer (score 0):

Does your home dev machine have a public IP address or is the firewall doing NAT and assigning it a private address (which would probably be a 192.168.x.y address, although 10.x.y.z or (rarely) 172.(16-31).x.y are also possibilities)?

- If it has a public IP address, you can configure your firewall to allow port 22 access to that address and it should Just Work(TM) from there.
- If it has a private IP address, you'll need to configure port forwarding on the firewall so that incoming port 22 connections to the firewall are redirected to the dev box.  Once that is set up, you should be able to ssh/scp to the firewall's public IP address and the connection will be transparently sent on to the dev box.